# How to make a custom class for UIPageViewControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uipageviewcontroller

I am writing an iOS app with a `UIPageViewController`. My root view controller is `ViewController`, and I added `UIPageViewController` as a child VC under it.

Initially, I made my `ViewController` as the page view VC delegate: `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`:

```
extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {



    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

        // set the pageControl.currentPage to the index of the current viewController in pages
        if let viewControllers = pageViewController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
            if let viewControllerIndex = self.detailPagedVC.pages.index(of: viewControllers[0]) {
                self.detailPagedVC.pageControl.currentPage = viewControllerIndex

                // if current page is a single person view controller, zoom to that person's face
                if let singlePersonViewController = self.detailPagedVC.pages[viewControllerIndex] as? SinglePersonPageViewController {

                    // print("didFinishAnimating: \(viewControllerIndex)")
                    self.zoomableImageVC.zoomableImageView.zoom(to: self.identificationResults[viewControllerIndex].face.rect, with: Constants.contentSpanRatio, animated: true)
                } else if let summaryPageViewController = self.detailPagedVC.pages[viewControllerIndex] as? SummaryPageViewController {
                    self.zoomableImageVC.zoomableImageView.zoom(to: self.zoomableImageVC.zoomableImageView.imageView.bounds, with: Constants.contentSpanRatio, animated: true)
                } else {
                    print("gw: err: unkown type of page controller in paged view ")
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

This way works fine. Until I decided to move the delegating function to a dedicated class:

```
class PeoplePageViewDelegate: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{

    private struct Constants {

        // the ratio of the content (e..g face) taken inside the entire view
        static let contentSpanRatio: CGFloat = 0.8

    }

    // store a reference to the object which will take the actual action
    // action 1: zooming
    weak var zoomingActionTaker: ZoomableImageView?

    // action 2: paging
    weak var pagingActionTaker: PeoplePageViewController?


    // the delegator who relies on this object
    unowned let delegator: PeoplePageViewController

    init(delegator: PeoplePageViewController) {
        self.delegator = delegator

        // wire back to delegator 
        // self.pagingActionTaker = delegator // gw: mind the nuance difference, you chain a weak ref on a unowned ref, what can go wrong?

        super.init()
    }




    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        print("gw:0")
        // set the pageControl.currentPage to the index of the current viewController in pages
        if let viewControllers = pageViewController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
            print("gw:1")
            if let viewControllerIndex = self.delegator.pages.index(of: viewControllers[0]) {
                 print("gw:2")
                self.pagingActionTaker?.pageControl.currentPage = viewControllerIndex

                // if current page is a single person view controller, zoom to that person's face
                if let singlePersonViewController = self.delegator.pages[viewControllerIndex] as? SinglePersonPageViewController {

                     print("gw:3")
                    self.zoomingActionTaker?.zoom(to: singlePersonViewController.identification.face.rect, with: Constants.contentSpanRatio, animated: true)


                } else if let summaryPageViewController = self.delegator.pages[viewControllerIndex] as? SummaryPageViewController,

                    let entireImageBounds = self.zoomingActionTaker?.imageView.bounds {
                    print("gw:4")
                    self.zoomingActionTaker?.zoom(to: entireImageBounds, with: Constants.contentSpanRatio, animated: true)
                } else {
                    print("gw: err: unkown type of page controller in paged view ")
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

This causes problem: the function `pageViewController(_: didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted)` is not called at all, despite I did set the delegate to a instance of this new class.

The only thing I can think of, is that the new delegate object is not a VC anymore (it used to be my main VC). So I suspect that this change of behavior is related to the VC hierachy ?

Did I miss something?

Comment: One possible reason might be that no one is keeping strong reference to the instance of `PeoplePageViewDelegate`. Please show how you _did set the delegate to a instance of this new class_.

Comment: @OOPer Here  it is: in the `init` of `ViewController`, I did: `let dedicatedDelegateObject = PeoplePageViewDelegate(param1, param2)`, then `self.pagedViewController.delegate = dedicatedDelegateObject`

Comment: 'OOPer I took a look at the `UIPageViewController.delegate` in apple document, it is a weak reference. I guess this is the cause?

Comment: Confirmed working. Put this in a answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Happy to hear that you have made it work. Please post an answer by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This answer is inspired by OOPer's comments).

It was found that the cause is because initially I only keep a `weak` reference to the delegate Object. Like this:

Before:

```
class ViewController:  UIViewController { 
    init() {

        self.pageViewController.delegate = PeoplePageViewDelegate(….)


    }

}
```

The problem here is once the execution point went pass the `init` method scope, the `PeoplePageViewDelegate` is garbage collected because its reference count is zero.

How I fixed it:

I added a strong reference as a field in my `ViewController`, so that it will retain the delegate object:

After:

```
class ViewController:  UIViewController { 

    var myStrongReference: PeoplePageViewDelegate?
    init() {

        self.myStrongReference = PeoplePageViewDelegate(….)

        self.pageViewController.delegate = self.myStrongReference

    }

}
```